# Adding Java sorting algorithms with a random array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

"To this program we will add the quick sort and the merge sort (non recursive)". I'm not sure how to do this with a random array. I formed this code so far, can  anyone help?

import java.util.Random;
public class Algo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Random gen = new Random();
int[] a = new int[20];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
a[i] = gen.nextInt(100);

printArray(a);
}

private static void printArray(int[] a){
for (int i : a)
System.out.print(i + " ");
System.out.println("");
}


}
```

}

Comment: Quick note, I think you want that println call outside of the for loop in printArray.

Answer (score 1):

To generate an array of random elements, try this:

```
int[] array = new int[20];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = random.nextInt();
```

... Afterwards you can work on your merge sort and quick sort algorithms. What have you done so far?

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] array) {
    // sorts the array in-place using merge sort algorithm
}

public static void quickSort(int[] array) {
    // sorts the array in-place using quick sort algorithm
}
```